# How to drop a website in Odoo with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, odoo-12, drop

My database of Odoo have multiple websites. I need to delete one of this website with postgres.

Can I do this :

```
DROP the_name_of_the_website IF EXISTS
```

Answer (score 1):

Julie Losange

This thing you can do by the Odoo `UI`, If you activate the developer mode you can see

```
 Website -> Configuration -> Websites
```

from here you can choose the website and `delete` it.

And On `Postgres` :

```
delete from website where id=YOUR WEBSITE ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

`DROP DATABASE [ IF EXISTS ] name` is the correct syntax, so

`DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS the_name_of_the_website`

in your case.

[See Postgres Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropdatabase.html)

Comment: Thank you @LarsSkaug for your response, but here, if i do that, the database will be deleted, right ? I need only the website to delete..

Comment: Yes, this will only delete a database in Postgres. I am not familiar with Odoo, but I would assume that you would get an error if the database cannot be found.